# Android OpenCV - changing resolusion from within onCameraFrame

Tags: android, opencv, resolution

I have a two stage app in which I need two sets of resolution:

### Stage 1

Searching for a known template \ QR markers within a frame.
In order to do so I need a frame size of at least 640X480.

### Stage 2

After finding the template \ QR markers I need to change to a lower resolution (320X240) in order to get the best frame rate I can for a time sensitive task.

### My problem

On start up (onCameraViewStarted) I can set the resolution to 640X480 but after that i cannot change it from within onCameraFrame (I locate the template \ QR markers from within onCameraFrame).
From some debugging i did it seems that the disconnectCamera() implemented by the setResolution method (as seen in OpenCV tutorial3) gets stuck waiting on the main thread to finish. Trying to change the resolution while using a new thread or by implementing an event listener didn't and up well also.

Any ideas on how can I change the resolution between the two stages ?

Thanks

Code:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    inFrame = inputFrame.gray();

    if (locateTemplate(inFrame)) {
        setResolution(WORK_RESOLUTION);
        resetGridData(WORK_RESOLUTION);
    }
    return inFrame;
}

/**
 * Sets a new resolution for camera frames
 * @param size - the new resolution size
 */
private void setResolution (Size size) {
    ListIterator<Camera.Size> iterator = cameraView.getResolutionList().listIterator();
    Camera.Size s;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        s = iterator.next();
        if (s.width == size.width && s.height == size.height) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting resolution to: " + s.width + "X" + s.height);
            cameraView.setResolution(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit with the tutorial i've noticed that onOptionsItemSelected() runs setResultion() from the main thread.

So... in order for you to be able to set the resultion from within onCameraFrame() you need to set it async from the thread that runs onCameraFrame().

I've used bolts-android.jar in order to set a new task that runs on the main thread:

```
/**
 * Sets a new resolution for camera frames
 * @param size - the new resolution size
 */
private void setResolution (Size size) {

    ListIterator<Camera.Size> iterator = cameraView.getResolutionList().listIterator();
    Camera.Size s;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        s = iterator.next();
        if (s.width == size.width && s.height == size.height) {
            final Camera.Size resSize = s;
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting resolution to: " + resSize.width + "X" + resSize.height);

            Task.call(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    cameraView.setResolution(resSize);
                    return null;
                }
            }, Task.UI_THREAD_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a new thread that you started from onCreate()...